# EmberData RESTAdapter, regular refresh on one page with url filter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a `Host` model that is, for the moment, pretty simple:

```
App.Host = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
```

The data adapter is handle by ember-data, my route looks like this:

```
App.HostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  init: ->
    @_super()
    @refresh()

  model: ->
    @store.find 'host',
      problematic: 1

  refresh: ->
    setTimeout =>
      @store.find('host', { problematic: 1 }).then (hosts) =>
        @controller.set 'content', hosts
      @refresh()
    , 10000
```

My template will show a list of boxes to list and manage nagios alerts:

```
<h2>Hosts list</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {{#each host in controller}}
            <div class="box box-solid box-default collapsed-box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h5 class="box-title">
                        <i class="fa fa-server"></i>
                        {{ host.name }}
                    </h5>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body no-padding table-responsive" style="display: none">
                    {{#link-to 'host' host}}{{host.name}}{{/link-to}}
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col/>
                            <col style="width: 100%"/>
                            <col/>
                            <col/>
                        </colgroup>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Service</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        {{/each}}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</div>
```

My boxes are collapsed by default and can be uncollapsed by a js trick.

In each refresh, boxes are again collapsed. In fact, **all the html** is rewritten.

If I try without the `problematic: 1` query parameter (calls `/hosts` instead of `/hosts?problematic=1`) it's works like a charm without rewriting all the html. The boxes stay uncollapsed.

So the problem source seems to be the additional query param but I don't know why.

What is wrong? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

UPDATE: Also tried with `filter` method:

```
  model: ->
    @store.filter 'host', {}, (host) ->
      host.get 'problematic'
    .then (hosts) ->
      hosts

  refresh: ->
    setTimeout =>
      @store.filter 'host', {}, (host) ->
        host.get 'problematic'
      .then (hosts) =>
        @controller.set 'content', hosts
      @refresh()
    , 10000
```

But same problem, change nothing.

I have absolutely no idea of why this not works with filter or query param...

Comment: you should be setting model, not content

Comment: when your model changes (as it is), ember must generate new html for it.  The upcoming Glimmer changes will prevent your html from needing to be fully refreshed, but until then, any DOM state you change manually needs to be able to handle underlying content changing.

Comment: How do set the model instead of the content? Some line code example please? And yes I can understand the concept of DOM rewrite but can you explain why this works perfectly with no query params on rest ajax call? (`problematic=1`). Thanks.

Comment: to set the model

'refresh: ->
    setTimeout =>
      @store.find('host', { problematic: 1 }).then (hosts) =>
        @controller.set 'model', hosts
      @refresh()
    , 10000`

Comment: So juste replace 'content' by 'model'? I tested, have exactly the same result. I'm missing something? What difference between 'model' and 'content'?